# Why is this code not updating my UITextField?

Tags: objective-c, ios

```
    if (![value integerValue]) {
        textField.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d", *x];
        [slider setValue:(float)*x];
    }
    if ([value integerValue]>100) {
        textField.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"255"];
        [slider setValue:100.0];
    }
    if ([value integerValue]<0) {
        textField.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"0"];
        [slider setValue:0.0];
    }

    [textField setText:value];
```

The textfield's value remains the one typed in, ignoring when I set it to a new value.

Can someone please explain why?

Comment: Is textField properly hooked up to your text field in IB? I'm also not sure what you're doing with "initWithFormat:@"%d",*x". Also, there's no need for any of those NSString alloc init's -- just use textField.text = @"255";

Answer (score 1):

```
[textField setText:value];
```

sets the UITextField value back to value.

Answer (score 1):

You are overwriting the `textField.text` property at the end of your method, no matter if it was "corrected" under one of your case-descisions.

Check that last line within your original code and note that `textField.text = xyz` is semantically equal to `[textField setText:xyz]`.

To fix your issue, use this corrected version of your code:

```
if (![value integerValue]) {
    textField.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d", *x];
    [slider setValue:(float)*x];
}
else if ([value integerValue]>100) {
    textField.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"255"];
    [slider setValue:100.0];
}
else if ([value integerValue]<0) {
    textField.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"0"];
    [slider setValue:0.0];
}
else {
    textField.text = value;
}
```